# Javascript magic conditions with 0 and null

Tags: javascript

Why in js `0<null` = false and `0==null` = false and `0<=null` = true ?
i have to reach a minimun number of character so i'm writing this.
Thanks

Comment: _"i have to reach a minimun number of character so i'm writing this"_ - Could be an indicator that your question has room for improvements... E.g. add a snippet that shows the actual behavior, explain what you've done so far for research, ...

Comment: As with most questions like this the answer is "because the spec says so and why are you comparing numbers to `null` in the first place?"

Comment: Read how the different operators in your question work: [Expressions and operators - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a know "feature" in JavaScript

```
alert( null > 0 );  // (1) false
alert( null == 0 ); // (2) false
alert( null >= 0 ); // (3) true
```

Its weird, but that is an expected behaviour in JavaScript

I think its explained well here [here](https://javascript.info/comparison#strange-result-null-vs-0)

> The reason is that an equality check `==` and comparisons `>` `<` `>=` `<=` work differently. Comparisons convert `null` to a number, treating it as `0`. That’s why (3) `null >= 0` is `true` and (1) `null > 0` is `false.`

Comment: When quoting an answer and it contains a reference like `(3)` and `(1)` then it would be useful to keep that information also in the quoted code. Also use `>` for quoting and not `\``